# Limits of two functions

Tags: limits, functions

Could you please help me or give me an advice for the following functions? I have to find their limits, but I find it difficult for me.
$$\lim _{x\to \pi }\left(\frac{1+sin\left(x\right)+cos\left(x\right)}{2cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}\right)$$
$$\lim _{x\to 1}\left(\frac{5-\sqrt{x+24}}{sin\left(1-x\right)}\right)$$

Comment: $$\sin x = 2\sin\frac x2\cos\frac x2,\quad 1 + \cos x = 2\cos^2 \frac x2$$

Comment: Ever heard about L'Hospital's Rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first is $$\lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{2(-\sin(x/2))\cdot \frac{1}{2}}=$$
the second one is equal to
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1}{\frac{\sin(1-x)}{1-x}(5+\sqrt{x+24})}$$